# Display driver has stopped responding and has recovered error. Nvidia GTX 960m

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Lenovo Y50-70 with a NVIDIA GTX 960m and lately I have been experiencing this weird error "Display driver has stopped responding and has recovered error". Usually it happens when browsing youtube and watching videos, but sometimes while coding in Visual Studio as well just scrolling down a class and the screen freezes for a second and then I get this error. What can I do? I've heard of using MSI Afterburner but I am not sure what I am supposed to edit?

Comment: Running 364.72? You're not alone. http://wccftech.com/nvidias-latest-game-ready-driver-allegedly-killing-gpus-plagued-issues/

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're encountering the error when Windows tries to switch from the integrated Intel GPU to the dedicated nVidia GPU. The issue may have originally been caused by an automatic Windows 10 update to either graphics card driver (you can check this in Start > Settings > Update and Security > Advanced Options > View Update History).

The first step would be to try uninstalling the nVidia driver and software: Right-click Start and select Programs and Features. Find the nVidia software in the list, uninstall it, restart the computer. Windows 10 will install the missing drivers after you restart. Test by watching YouTube.

If that doesn't fix the issue, you may wish to visit the Lenovo support site and download the latest nVidia drivers for your laptop and install them. However, they may be an older version than what Windows 10 had installed...but at least they're stable. You may also need to (less likely) do the same for the Intel video driver. If you run into difficulties installing the Lenovo drivers and/or the problem reoccurs, check the Windows update history (as above) because you may need to disable the automatic update of that driver by Windows 10.

Comment: I have no idea why. How did you go after uninstalling? I'm assuming Windows 10 successfully reinstalled the nVidia drivers after a reboot?